# Why does `get_permalink()` produces an add. DB request without $post->filter?

Tags: permalinks, wp-query, query

I'm currently working on a custom loop/query where I need to add the permalink of a post to the array of posts I'm retrieving from the DB.

Sadly `get_permalink()` produces one additional DB request for every call, which can get pretty intense as I'm listing **all** posts on one page.

I first thought it might be that calls to [`get_option( 'permalink_structure' );`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L113) *or* [`get_option( 'default_category' );`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L132) are no auto loaded options, but both are auto loaded. Proof here:

```
function wpse_list_autoloaded_opts()
{
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT option_name, option_value 
        FROM $wpdb->options 
        WHERE autoload = 'yes'
    " );

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach( $results as $result ) 
        if ( 'permalink_structure' === $result->option_name OR 'default_category' === $result->option_name ) 
            echo "Name: {$result->option_name}, Value: {$result->option_value}<br />";
    echo '<pre>';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'wpse_list_autoloaded_opts' );
```

---

**EDIT:** Ok, I managed to track it down to [the following lines](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2/wp-includes/link-template.php#L95) inside the `get_permalink()` function.

```
if ( is_object($id) && isset($id->filter) && 'sample' == $id->filter ) {
        $post = $id;
        $sample = true;
    } else {
        $post = &get_post($id);
        $sample = false;
    }
```

**So my Q is now:** How would I avoid running the `else` part, which calls `get_post()` and does the additional query?

---

**EDIT 2:** Now found out that the docBlock of `get_permalink()` is as wrong as the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink). You can pass the whole `$post` object into the function too. This solves the `if ( is_object($id)` part.

**Still open:** From where the heck would I retrieve `$post->filter` with a value of `'sample'`?

---

**EDIT 3:** Adding `$post->filter = 'sample'` to each post object solves the problem. But what remains is a bad feeling that I might break something. The `'sample'` in `$id/$post->filter` seems pretty strange and I can't find out where it comes from.

Comment: [Track ticket added](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18822)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My workaround for this problem:

```
unset( $post->filter );

$url = get_permalink( $post );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1. It works as my workaround (without beeing such ugly), but I still can't make any sense out of the core part of this Q.

Comment: You'll make (some) sense of it if you run `ack-grep "'sample'"` on the wp dir.

Comment: Nice work scribu!

Comment: Sidenote, as you as core contributer can shurely give me an answer: Why does this even has to have be there? it could simply be `is_object($id) XOR ( isset($id->filter) && 'sample' == $id->filter )` or am I wrong? In this case both _should_ work. Yes/No?

Comment: I don't know, off the top of my head. To answer that, one would have to do some "blaming" on trac: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-admin/includes/post.php (there's an Annotate link on the upper-right corner).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that feature. For further readers: "_Fix permalink editor for pages, hide "View Post" button while editing permalink, fixes #9040_". Change is 3 years old. Seems like I'll have to open a new ticket.